# Application Object and Its Memory Management

Tags: android, memory-management

Basically I know something related to topic like what is application object and when should we use it. but still there are some questions which need to be responded on my mind.

Lets suppose that we have a project which includes custom application and in somewhere, the project throws an error and appears force close.

So will application object be still alive? If yes how and when will it get dispose?

Comment: "Falls to force close"? Do you mean *fails*? If there is an uncaught error, the app force closes and nothing remains in memory.

Comment: this is exactly what I want to point. In my application there is something still remains in memory even if force close appears. I have checked it with ActivityManager.MemoryInfo and obviously there were something remain.